# Bing Maps AJAX control 7.0 connect to SQL DB

Tags: asp.net, sql, ajax, asp.net-ajax, bing-maps

I am trying to link a SQL db to my Bing Map on my website. I would like to be able to query the database, controlled by user searches, to display the search results on the map as pushpins with simple infoboxes including a couple descriptors also available in the DB and the queries.

I have looked into the DataConnector (http://dataconnector.codeplex.com/), however I would like to avoid Silverlight and stick with AJAX. If possible any connectors written in ASP would be a plus. Also I saw the feature using GeoRSS feeds to plot data. Maybe this solution would work when querying my DB?

Does anyone have a good solution for this with minimal coding? I want to keep it nice and simple.

Thank you all in advance for your help!

Comment: What's wrong with using jquery ajax requests to relay the search input to your asp.net methods, have the server crank out the result, return them via json, convert results to javascript objects and populate your pushpins?

Answer (score 1):

http://ajaxmapdataconnector.codeplex.com/ as listed on the http://dataconnector.codeplex.com/ homepage will give you what you want